# JSP Files Not Accessible To Public

Tags: jsp, web-applications, glassfish

I have following structure in my web application:

`/BookMeetingWebApplication/|

  |-- Web Pages

      |-- WEB-INF

      |-- admin

      |-- resources

      |-- users

      |[LIST OF JSP FILES HERE]`

My problem is that those list of jsp files under Web Pages folder is not accessible to public. What is the reason? How I can fix this?

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2.2 server with JDBC Realm. They work fine and other folders are accessible to logged user as defined.

Comment: You may want to check the access.log and add any info from there that seems appropriate.  The server log may also have info that would be useful to help diagnose this issue.  You may want to include a sample of the URLs that fail and also a couple that are successful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. About the access.log it is empty because I noticed that I wasn't enabled it before in GlassFish's HTTP Service section, so now I enabled it and refreshed the browser but still no logs was written. Server log doesn't give either any information. I have CreateUser.jsp html link under login.jsp but whenever I click that link it won't load the page, it stays as the same. In login.jsp file there's also other link called RequestLoginDetails.jsp and when I click it, same happens like CreateUser.jsp case. I can only access them if I'm logged in.

Comment: Nobody knows the solution for this problem?